# Counting rows in a Query containing Join

Tags: mysql, count

I have a query that goes like this:

```
SELECT Product.local_price*Rate.exchange_rate AS 'US_price' FROM Product
 INNER JOIN Rate ON Rate.currency = Product.currency
 WHERE Product.type='TV'
 HAVING US_price BETWEEN 500 AND 600;
```

How do I do a count on the number of TV sets that satisfy this query?

**Table structure**

- Product Table: ID, type, local_price
- Rate Table: currency, exchange_rate

Comment: Why do you use `HAVING` here?

Comment: Do you have an alternative suggestion?

Comment: I mean, does this query even work?

Comment: Give us your table structure and tell on which base you want to count TV sets?

Comment: Sorry, should be US price instead of local price.

Comment: `having` requires to use *single value functions*. Why are you using the `between` clause?

Comment: @Lion: is that so? Any reference to this. Because I can get results with `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Was this query compiled when you tried?

Comment: Yes, it works without any error. But ruakh is right, I can put it in `WHERE` instead. The rows returned matched with my original query.

Comment: @Lion: I know this is not proper SQL, but MySQL allows this to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use a `HAVING` clause here; its special semantics are only relevant when you have a `GROUP BY` clause. So, we can simply replace `US_price` in the `HAVING` clause with the expression that generates it, and move it into the `WHERE` clause; and then, use `SELECT COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Product
  JOIN Rate
    ON Rate.currency = Product.currency
 WHERE Product.type = 'TV'
   AND Product.US_price * Rate.exchange_rate BETWEEN 500 AND 600
;
```

Also, as a general rule — not needed in this case — you can always (or almost always?) wrap your entire query in `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (...) t` to get the total number of rows it returns.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `HAVING US_price` with `AND Product.local_price * Rate.exchange_rate` and just do a `COUNT(Product.ID)` in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(Product.ID) 
FROM Product 
  INNER JOIN Rate ON Rate.currency = Product.currency 
WHERE Product.type='TV' 
  AND Product.local_price * Rate.exchange_rate BETWEEN 500 AND 600;
```

You would want to use a `HAVING` if you wanted criteria on aggregated data, like this:

```
SELECT p.type, AVG(p.local_price)
FROM Product p
GROUP BY p.type
HAVING AVG(p.local_price) > 50
```